# FUEL-CMS module file location issue while using $foreign_keys or $belongs_to

Tags: php, fuelcms

hi i was trying to use the $foreign_keys feature as follow

```
public $foreign_keys = array('continent_id' => array(FUEL_FOLDER => 'continents_model'));
```

but getting the error

> ```
> An Error Was Encountered
>
> Unable to locate the file: continents_model.php
> ```

same thing happens while i tried to use `$belongs_to`

the location of those modules were :

```
\fuel\modules\packages\models 
\fuel\modules\continents\models
```

my folder structure as per the image

[image]

my model code as follow

[image]

what change should i do so it can get the model path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is with using FUEL_FOLDER instead of the name of the module. Try the following instead:

```
public $foreign_keys = array('continent_id' => array('continents' => 'continents_model'));
```